# Is this an example of recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, tkinter

In Python Tkinter, I have a function that produces a button. when it is clicked on it runs the same function. e.g.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def CreateButton():
    btnPushMe = Button(text="click me",command=lambda: CreateButton()).grid(row=random.randint(0,10),column=random.randint(0,10))

root = Tk()

root.title("Is this recursion?")
root.geometry("500x250")
CreateButton()
```

I would like to know if this is an example of recursion?

Comment: no because the callback won't be called from your `CreateButton` routine but from the mainloop.

Comment: recursion is a function calling itself.

Comment: Don't bother with the assignment in `CreateButton`.  `btn_PushMe` is bound to `None` (`grid`'s return value) and then immediately deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, no, it is not an example of recursion. In the simplest terms, a recursive function has two parts:

1. a part that returns a value without needing to call itself
2. a part that calls itself

Nowhere in your code do you directly call a function from itself, you are merely creating objects that may or may not call the function at some point in the future.